# What am I doing wrong? Java IllegalFormatConversionException

Tags: java

I have some code for calculating properties of a circle:

```
package circleinfo;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Circleinfo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int r;

        System.out.print("Enter the radius of the circle to find circumference, diameter, and area\n");

        r = input.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("The circumference is %f\n",(2*r*Math.PI));
        System.out.printf("The diameter is %f\n",(r*2));
        System.out.printf("The area is %f\n",(r*r*Math.PI));

    }
}
```

It calculates circumference, but not the rest.

```
Enter the radius of the circle to find circumference, diameter, and area

10

The circumference is 62.831853

Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4045)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2761)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2708)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2488)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at circleinfo.Circleinfo.main(Circleinfo.java:30)
The diameter is Java Result: 1
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("The diameter is %f\n",(r*2));` in there `r*2` is an integer but you're calling printf on it like a float. Use `%d` instead of `%f` there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`r` is an `int`, so `r*2` is also an `int`, meaning that in your second print statement `%f` cannot be used. Try `%d` there instead.

Recall that `%f` is for floating point numbers while `%d` is for integers. This is outlined in the documentation of [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) (see [Format String Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)).

Answer (score 3):

`(r*2)` will be an `int` and not a `float` as `r` is `int` and `2` is `int`. Use `%d` instead

```
%c          char    Character
%d          int         Signed decimal integer.  
%e, %E      float       Real number, scientific notation (lowercase or uppercase exponent marker)
%f         float    Real number, standard notation.
```

Comment: What do we use for double?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you had to put `%d` format instead of `%f` in the result of the diameter

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CircleInfo{
    public static void main(String[] args){

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int radio;
            System.out.print("Input radio: ");
            radio = input.nextInt();

            System.out.printf("%s%d%n","Diameter= ",(2*radio));
            System.out.printf("%s%f%n","Area= ",(Math.PI*radio*radio));
            System.out.printf("%s%f%n","Circumference = ",(2*Math.PI*radio));
    }
}
```