# I am having trouble with printf() in Java

Tags: java, printf

I am working on a Java assignment and I have written this simple code before; however, our professor this semester is more interested in how we format the code than whether it just works or not. I have 2 statements using printf that function properly, but the 3rd one does not. I changed it to a println statement with the average and it prints fine, but I need to use the printf for this assignment. If I comment out the printf for average, then the first 2 printf statements run without error.

```
        //Set variables for calculations and perform arithmetic
        int sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
        double average = (double)sum/3;
        int product = num1 * num2 * num3;
        int smallest;
        int largest;
        
        System.out.printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum);
        System.out.printf("The product is: %d\n", product);
        System.out.printf("The average is: %d\n", average);
```

The error is as follows:

```
The sum is: Exception in thread "main" 10
The product is: 18
The average is: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4426)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2938)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2892)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2673)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1209)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:1105)
    at Assignment_1.main(Assignment_1.java:49)
```

Comment: The correct format specifier for a `double` is `%f`, not `%d` (since a `double` is a floating-point type that can represent a non-integer value). The full documentation for [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) discusses more details including other rules and features available in format strings.

Comment: Please refer this for your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18542524/9970310

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.out.printf("The average is: %f\n", average);`

Instead of `System.out.printf("The average is: %d\n", average);`

Because the format of a double variable is `%f` (`%d` is for an integer)

`println` worked correctly because it automatically formats variables.

Comment: Thank you X Y. I thought of that this morning when I woke up and was planning on trying it when I get home from work today; however, my management just called and we are working from home today due to someone in our office testing positive for COVID.

Comment: @Lee Baldwin if this answer solves your problem, mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

It happens because your average is a double, not a integer. When you try to print average, you are using `%d` and it is a conversion specifier for int values. Change it to `%f` might resolve your problem.